# glibc make process crashing while trying to stat a nonexistant file

Tags: linux, makefile, glibc

I am trying to compile glibc for my Linux distro (note that I am not using LFS) and while compiling via make an error has occured:

```
gcc -B/cross-tools/bin/ sdlvsym.c -c -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline  -g -O2 -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Werror -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -fno-stack-protector -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -fmath-errno    -fcf-protection   -ftls-model=initial-exec   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE   -I../include -I/mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/dlfcn  -I/mnt/d/akari/glibc-build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/x86/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/float128  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96/include -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I. -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include -isystem /usr/include  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h  -DPIC     -DTOP_NAMESPACE=glibc -o /mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/dlfcn/sdlvsym.o -MD -MP -MF /mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/dlfcn/sdlvsym.o.dt -MT /mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/dlfcn/sdlvsym.o
mv: cannot stat '/mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/dlfcn/stamp.oST': No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [../o-iterator.mk:9: /mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/dlfcn/stamp.oS] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/akari/glibc-2.32/dlfcn'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:470: dlfcn/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/akari/glibc-2.32'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

I do not know why this has happened. After searching through the makefile I suppose it is a cache file. If anyone would be willing to help me, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Did you look at line 470 of the file `dlfcn/Makefile` and see what the command is there?

Comment: 1. There is no makefile in dlfcn
2. In the normal makefile, in the line 470 there is only the command to start compiling

Comment: Sorry I misread the output.  The error is here: `../o-iterator.mk:9`  So look at line 9 of the o-iterator.mk file.

Comment: The 9th line is: $(o-iterator-doit)

Comment: And the whole code of the file is:
o := $(firstword $(object-suffixes-left))
object-suffixes-left := $(filter-out $o,$(object-suffixes-left))

$(o-iterator-doit)

Comment: It's impossible to understand makefile code in comments because there's no formatting.  Please update the question to have a properly-formatted version of this rule.  If the 9th line is a variable, you'll have to go find out what that variable is set to.  Also if you can figure out how to turn off "quiet" mode for these targets so make will print the commands that are being run (which it will do by default, so someone must have turned that off) then it will probably help you track down the issue.

Comment: @MadScientist I think I know what caused the problem. I tried running ./configure, but instead of setting -O1 in the CFLAGS which I did before, I set -O2, -fPIC and ran it as root. Now it is progressing!

Comment: I believe you that re-running `configure` with different options will fix the problem.  But I don't believe that changing `CFLAGS=-O1` to `CFLAGS='-O2 -fpic'` or running as root (you should never do that!) will fix the problem  If you showed us the original configure line (exactly, cut and pasted from your shell history) and the new one it might be more clear.  But, good that it works now!

Comment: Ok, it crashed. Perfect. It did proceed further but it crashed at the final link. And also, why shouldn't I run as root?

Answer (score 0):

If you issue an `mkdir -p /mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/dlfcn && touch /mnt/d/akari/glibc-build/dlfcn/stamp.oST`, the build will proceed further.